# How to display a widget available for all themes

Tags: widgets

I have just created my first WordPress widget ("hello world" style) and was able to display it correctly. But what I notice that if I change my theme then my created widget disappears from available widget area in admin panel; though there are many widgets which are always showed regardless of chosen theme (Like Text widget). I want to know how can I make my widget available across all the themes?

Comment: is your widget code part of a theme or [in a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin)?

Comment: @Milo Its actually in a theme. How can I create it as a plugin? Can you suggest any tutorial. Sorry I am newbie in wordpress coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your custom widget code into a separate php file, [add a plugin header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
 * Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
 * Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
 * Author: Name Of The Plugin Author
 * Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
 * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */
```

then upload it to your plugins directory and activate it. That's it!

Comment: Thx. Will definitely try it.